# I can't run applicaton when using '<ViewCell.ContextActions>' on Xamarin Form (PCL)?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Position 37:61. Type Regerence not found in xmlns http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml  Course_3

```
<ViewCell>
                        <Grid>
                            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
                                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
                            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                            <Grid Grid.Column="0">
                                <Image Source="{Binding PhotoUrl}" HeightRequest="70"></Image>
                            </Grid>

                            <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Padding="5">
                                <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black" Margin="0,5"></Label>
                                <Label Text="{Binding City}" FontSize="10" TextColor="Black" Margin="0,5"></Label>
                                <Label Text="{Binding JobTitle}" FontSize="10" TextColor="#CCCCCC" Margin="0,5"></Label>
                            </StackLayout>
                            <ViewCell.ContextActions>
                                <MenuItem Text="Edit" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Root}, Path=BindingContext.EditCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding}"></MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem Text="Delete" Command="{Binding Source={x:Regerence Root},Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand}"
                                          CommandParameter="{Binding}"></MenuItem>
                            </ViewCell.ContextActions>
                        </Grid>

                    </ViewCell>
```

Comment: Please also consider upvoting the answer if it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should move the `<ViewCell.ContextActions>` part outside of the `Grid` control. It needs to be a direct child of `ViewCell`. Don't know if this is a type you also made in code but change `{x:Regerence Root}` to `{x:Reference Root}` for the second menu item. Also your question would probably benefit from some editing to improve its overall quality.

```
<ViewCell> 
    <ViewCell.ContextActions>
        <MenuItem Text="Edit" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Root}, Path=BindingContext.EditCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"></MenuItem>
        <MenuItem Text="Delete" Command="{Binding Source={x:Reference Root},Path=BindingContext.DeleteCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="{Binding}"></MenuItem>
    </ViewCell.ContextActions>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="100"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <Grid Grid.Column="0">
            <Image Source="{Binding PhotoUrl}" HeightRequest="70"></Image>
        </Grid>

        <StackLayout Grid.Column="1" Padding="5">
            <Label Text="{Binding FullName}" FontSize="15" TextColor="Black" Margin="0,5"></Label>
            <Label Text="{Binding City}" FontSize="10" TextColor="Black" Margin="0,5"></Label>
            <Label Text="{Binding JobTitle}" FontSize="10" TextColor="#CCCCCC" Margin="0,5"></Label>
        </StackLayout>
    </Grid>

</ViewCell>
```

Comment: It ok but ListView item source binding is ItemsSource="{Binding Acquaintances}" => when I click menu items then the property is null.